# Should I worry about my website performance since tomcat 9 is not using blocking io

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, tomcat9

I was working on my spring MCV project and using tomcat 9 then i notice something strange.
my tomcat log was saying

```
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

After some searching I found on tomcat official site.

> The Java blocking IO implementation (BIO) for both HTTP and AJP has
>   been removed. Users are recommended to switch to the Java non-blocking
>   IO implementation (NIO).

It means tomcat no longer using blocking-IO,

Now i am little bit confused and scared about my web application performance.

I am not using any non-blocking code in my web application.
The thing i heard non-blocking structure runs on single thread for all request.

Does it means my application will not work properly on multiple request?.

like my all code is blocking when i am writing files, connecting to databases.

so does it mean now my structure is running like node?

should i worry about it?

please help.

Comment: Don't know much about tomcat but you appear to confuse `non blocking` and `blocking`, blocking means it will process one after another, non blocking means parallel processing is possible.

Comment: blocking mean it will create new thread for each request while for non-blocking it will put all request in queue then a single thread will process one after another.

Comment: I am 99% sure it's the other way around.

Comment: So, should i worry about performance?

Comment: Just for reference [blocking vs non-blocking](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html). And perhaps you are looking for - [nio-performance-improvement-compared-to-traditional-io-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611152/nio-performance-improvement-compared-to-traditional-io-in-java)